# Why can we choose a gamma matrix to be diagonal?

Tags: representation-theory, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I am reading the textbook "Lectures on Quantum Field Theory", second edition by Ashok Das. On page 21, in equation (1.83), he writes the properties of gamma matrices:

$$
 ( \gamma^0)^2   = {1\!\!1}, \\
 ( \gamma^i)^2   = -{1\!\!1}, \text{ for any fixed i =1,2,3} \\
 \gamma^0 \gamma^i + \gamma^i \gamma^0 = 0, \\
 \gamma^i \gamma^j + \gamma^j \gamma^i = 0, \text{ i $\ne$ j} \\
$$

He then says "We can choose any one of the matrices to be diagonal and " goes on to choose $\gamma^0$ to be diagonal.

Question: How can we be sure from this information that $\gamma^0$ is diagonalizable?

PS: I can post this question on math.stackexchange but since it stems from a physics textbook, I prefer to keep it on physics.stackexchange.

Comment: Even for Dirac, in his original paper, what he did was to simply try by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, [$\gamma^0$ is diagonal in the Dirac representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices), and you can check that the $\gamma$-matrices at the link satisfy the anticommutation relations, on the other hand, according to [Pauli’s fundamental theorem](https://cheng.physics.ucdavis.edu/teaching/230A-s07/rqm3_rev.pdf), for any two sets of gamma-matrices $\gamma^\mu$ and $\gamma'^\mu$, there is a non-singular matrix $S$ such that $\gamma'^\mu=S\gamma^\mu S^{-1}$.